# Can't close a Popup Dialog Box with Selenium Webdriver Python(Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with)

Tags: jquery, selenium

I can't close jquery dialog box with selenium webdriver.Here is my code.I'm using Selenium WebDriver version: 2.44.0, Firefox version: 33.Any idea please.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://122.155.222.114/ev57/login/login.aspx')
time.sleep(5)

#I use inspect element in firebug
#<div style="float: right; cursor: pointer; display: block;" class="dialog-icon-close" role="button">X</div>

#browser.execute_script('$(".dialog-icon-close").click();')
#This work but maybe not the selenium way.

elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dialog-icon-close')
#This produce error
#ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
elem.click()
```

**Edit**: I use this method now,It works but maybe not good enough.

```
#browser.execute_script('$(".dialog-icon-close").click();')
#This work but maybe not the selenium way.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

This will work.

```
browser.switchto().alert();
browser.find_element_by_class_name('dialog-icon-close')

//Returns you to your main frame of reference.
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

---

**Editing Elements in IFrame.**

This code below is used for getting at elements withing an Iframe, or seperate frame in general and doesn't work for this question.

Python:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("frameid")) 
browser.find_element_by_class_name('dialog-icon-close').click()

//Returns you to your main frame of reference.
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

C#:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElementById("frameid"));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("dialog-icon-close")).Click();
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Java:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameid");
driver.findElement(By.id("dialog-icon-close")).click(); 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Spoilers *(Hover mouse over)*

> Notice Java is similar you C# except some methods are lowercase, while in C# they've become uppercase. Interesting.

Comment: I checked the the source code by using inspect in firebug,there is no frame for jquery box.

Comment: I'll be back in a few minutes. I'm going to play in jsfiddle.net to test selenium with some popup boxes.

Comment: Have you tried using driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept; or trying driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); then search for that element click it, then driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

Comment: browser.switch_to_alert().accept()
#NoAlertPresentException: Message: No alert is present

Comment: browser.switch_to_alert()
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dialog-icon-close')
elem.click()
#ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with